# I wanna open cmd in normal window with python

Tags: python

I have a problem
I want to open cmd in a normal (or maximized) window, but I don't know what I should do.
the

```
import os
os.system('start')
```

open cmd in a minimized window, but I wanna open cmd in a normal or maximized window
Is there a feature or command that you can use to open cmd in another size?

Comment: why do you need to open it in the first place? and a 100 times? you are not even doing anything with it. anyways, you may need to use some Windows API for that but we need more information and what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Method get need type name https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.get `webbrowser.get("chrome")`

Try to use `get` 2 times according to [example](https://devtut.github.io/python/webbrowser-module.html#opening-a-url-with-different-browsers):

```
import webbrowser
browser_path = webbrowser.get(chrome_path)
chrome = webbrowser.get(browser_path)
chrome.open(url)
```